# Is it possible to use Ruby temp directory engine with non-english file names on Windows?

Tags: ruby

I am creating a temporary directory in Ruby using 'tmpdir', and adding a file in the temporary directory that has a non-English file name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -KU
# coding:utf-8

require 'tmpdir'
Dir.mktmpdir { |dir| File.open( "#{dir}/файл.txt", "w" ) {} }
```

The program fails on cleanup, attempting to delete "????.txt". I can see the file is being created with the appropriate name.

I am running Ruby 1.9 on Windows. Is there some way to fix this, or is Ruby 1.9 not intended to be used with non-English characters on Windows?

Comment: You might try putting `# encoding: utf-8` instead of `# coding: utf-8` at the top of your file.

Comment: According to Ruby documentation, "encoding" and "coding" works the same. Anyway, i have checked it, nothing changes :(.

Comment: Are your locale settings set appropriately? Try `locale-gen ru_utf8 ru_RU.UTF-8`.

Comment: According to Ruby documentation, "coding" statusline overrides locale environment variable. Also, where is no locale-gen on Windows. Anyway, i have checked this with windows alternative to locale-gen, an "LANG" environment variable. Nothing changes :(.

Comment: Can you see characters when you print them out directly to the console (`puts "файл"`)? If not, the problem could be your font (default console font doesn't support unicode characters). Try changing to a true type font (see [this article](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html)) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. Absolutely no connection between console and filesystem operation. Creating and deleting files has no connection to outputting they names to console. BTW, nix console is ASCII by design.

Comment: What I had in mind is : for some reason, your file is not getting created in the first place. Then, you get a message saying that you can't delete "????.txt", but this is actually an encoding problem with your console and should really read cant delete "файл.txt". So that the problem would be one of file permissions rather than encoding. My question was meant to eliminate that possibility - just trying to help here.

Comment: @louism This assumption is wrong - file is being created with correct name. Problem is - Dir.mktmpdir can't delete it for some reason that is unknown for me. Also, if i change name from "файл.txt" to "file.txt" all works fine - so it's definitely not a permission problem.

Comment: @lousim: The windows console doesn't even support unicode or UTF-8, so the suggest to use `puts` to test whether Ruby has the right locale set is indeed nonsense.
Eye of Hell: If the file is created with the correct name but not deleted, it could actually be a Ruby bug. Which exact version are you using? Also, have you tried using the [`Tempfile`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Tempfile) module? I think it's used more often.

Comment: @Niklas I'm using latest RubyInstaller for windows, AFAIK it's 1.9.3-p0. Unfortunately, i need `Dir#mktmpdir` since my script create many temporary files, so `Tempfile` is no use.

Comment: I thought the shebang notation (#!) didn't work on Windows. Did you try to run the script from the command line with the `-KU` switch? `ruby -KU test.rb`

Comment: @alfonso The shebang works on windows (checked on another code). Running with -KU interpreter switch don't change anything :(.

Comment: @EyeofHell: Can you use some ASCII representation of the non-english characters? If you are making temporary files, I see no need for them to be localized. Is there a reason that is not mentioned?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh The non-ASCII characters in file names are results of running third-party program over arbitrary set of data, namely subversion command-line client targeting arbitrary repository. Some repository do have non-ASCII file names :(. It's a cruel real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced more than 2 years ago by typo. Will be fixed in Ruby 2.0 :(
http://goo.gl/SsAA8

For ruby version < 2.0 this hack defined after `require 'tmpdir'` will fix a problem:

```
if RUBY_VERSION < '2.0' then
  ##  Fix bug |http://goo.gl/SsAA8|.
  class FileUtils::Entry_
    def entries
      opts = {}
      opts[:encoding] = "UTF-8" if /mswin|mingw/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM
      Dir.entries(path(), opts)\
          .reject {|n| n == '.' or n == '..' }\
          .map {|n| FileUtils::Entry_.new(prefix(), join(rel(), n.untaint)) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i'm pretty sure this is a bug. The method tmpdir is using the cleanup after itself can't recognize the utf-8 filename (probably a ruby/windows problem or ruby-specific)

The following would be a workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -KU
# coding:utf-8

require 'tmpdir'
Dir.mktmpdir do |dir| 
  File.open( "#{dir}/файл.txt", "w" ) {} 
  FileUtils.remove_entry_secure "#{dir}/файл.txt"
end
```

This removes the 'odd' file before removing the folder. A Little bit of a hack, but it should work (tested it).

Comment: Yes, this will work, but in reality filenames are not of my creation - they are created by third-party code, for example Subversion command-line client.

Comment: In this case you would need a way to get the real filenames with a systemcall like:
    %x[dir]
since rubys Dir.entries returns the wrongly encoded '???' version.

Comment: Thanks for `Dir.entries` hint. I have searched Ruby source code and found a problem - it is indeed a Ruby bug caused by a typo many years ago and it may be fixed in Ruby 2.0. Reputation is yours :).